# combine channels function problem - python 3

Tags: python

I have an assigment which I need to build a function that recieving X color channels and combine it into one, like this:
the function receive:

```
[[[1]], [[2]]]) → [[[1, 2]]]
```

but from somereason my function return this

```
[[[1], [2]]]
```

```
def combine_channels(channels):
    channels_num = len(channels[0][0])
    channel_row = []
    new_channel = []
    channel_combine = []
    pixle_index = 0
    while pixle_index < channels_num:
        for i in image:
            for j in i:
                channel_row.append(j[pixle_index])
            new_channel.append(channel_row)
            channel_row = []
        channel_combine.append(new_channel)
        new_channel = []
        pixle_index += 1
    return channel_combine
```

> **NB**: I only can import sys and math if its help somehow.

Comment: can you give example input for image? Or `[[[1,2],[1,2],[1,4]]]` is just input?

Comment: This is and input example that we got :)

Comment: I assume it's having tons more, so X, Y 2 dimension and N number of color channels per pixel?

Comment: Yes exactly! its a 2 dimension and N number of color channels per pixel(at least 1 though)

Comment: Then isn't input wrong? can you check example again? or that [1, 2] [1, 2]... is a separate pixel?

Comment: combine_channels([[[1]], [[2]]]) → [[[1, 2]]] You right, I didnt copy the right example

Comment: can you edit and update example to question in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got how image looks like, will make assumption your professor actually will input like this:

```py
[
 # channels
 [
  # rows
  [1, 2, 3, ...],  # pixels
  [4, 5, 6, ...],
  ...
 ],

 # channels
 [
  # rows
  [1, 2, 3, ...],
  [4, 5, 6, ...],
  ...
 ],

]
```

Code:

```py
>>> def combine_channels(image):
...     copy = []
...     for row_pairs in zip(*image):
...          copy.append([channel_combined for channel_combined in zip(*row_pairs)])
...     return copy

>>> combine_channels([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]])
[[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)], [(4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)]]

>>> combine_channels([[[1]], [[2]]])
[[(1, 2)]]
```

Comment: Hi, first of all I really want to thank you, I really apprecaite you help! The code is right but I just wrote that I accidently copied the wrong example as you though at the beggining.. This function suppose to recieve this input : combine_channels([[[1]], [[2]]]) and return : [[[1, 2]]]
. While the code you wrote returning this: [[[1]], [[2]]]. Again, thank you very much, I am trying this for hours with no succses. Unfortounatly I just started coding and we recieved a task that is way above our level..

Comment: Better edit and update question then! For new case, what's the channel then?

Comment: I edited the question above :) The function suppose to recieve channels and not Image, and combine it into a image. I hope you understood, because I barely understood myself. Anyway As you can see I edited the example above :)

Comment: updated, if you prefer list over tuple, wrap `[]` with `list()`

Comment: You are invited to my wedding. Much appreciatation!

Comment: You are invited to my wedding. Much appreciatation! Do you just know if it’s possible to do it without the ()? If it’s impossible it’s still great

Comment: I told you above, wrap [] with list()